# Complex Shinydashboard structure with menuItems and tabs

Tags: layout, shiny, tabs, structure, shinydashboard

First of all, I don't have a reproducible example as I am still thinking about the structure of my future dashboard. Here are the requirements:

- using a menu on the left (currently thinking about `dashboardSidebar()` from `shinydashboard`) with 4 different items: filters, comparison, prediction, and data. Each item has subitems that applies to the current dataset (set of filters, chosen comparison variables)
- tabs for each product category (e.g. one tab for fruits, another for veggies, another for meat, etc...). I've read that it is not recommended to use `tabset()` from `shiny` with `shinydashboard` components.
  The idea is that the components on the left menu apply to the current tab, but the menu is the same across all tabs.
  Here is a visual example of what is expected:

[ideal dashboard structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVCZm.png)

I am new to Shiny and would highly appreciate the hints from the experts out there. Thanks!

Comment: Your post reminds me of [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-developer-challenge-the-perfect-dashboard-design/69513). However, if you'd like to stick with basic `shinydashboard` components I'd recommend using a [tabBox](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#tabbox) in the dashboard body along with the sidebar. Alternatively you could use the [message-menus](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#message-menus) in the header.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give a try to the tabBox solution at first (KISS method)

Comment: You're welcome! If you run into problems and you're able to provide an example, let me know.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918445/reproduce-a-flexdashboard-layout-with-shinydashboard/62929783#62929783) you can find a related answer.