# Reproduce a flexdashboard layout with shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to reproduce a `flexdashboard` simple layout with a persistent sidebar and several tabs. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820406/make-inputs-in-a-sidebar-persistent-through-tabs) I asked recently but in the latter I used some code found in another SO answer, whereas in this question I use straightforward `flexdashboard` code.

Here's a simple `flexdashboard` layout:

````
---
title: "Title of a Shiny app"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
textInput("test", "test")
actionButton("test_2", "test 2")
```

Tab 1
=====================================  

Tab 2
=====================================  

Tab 3
=====================================
````

You can see that it mixes a persistent sidebar with a navbar.

However, I don't know how to reproduce this in `shinydashboard`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    textInput("test", "test"),
    actionButton("test_2", "test 2")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1"),
      tabPanel("Tab 2"),
      tabPanel("Tab 3") 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The tabs in this example are not a navbar, like in the `flexdashboard` example.

Is there a **simple** way (i.e not using dozens of lines of CSS) to produce the `flexdashboard` example using `shinydashboard` (or other solution)?

Comment: maybe `{shinydashboardPlus }` is an option here. Haven't gotten the result I wanted yet though and it's another dependency also.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is an option for you, but you could use shinydashboard's [dropdownMenu](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#message-menus) and a `hidden` dashboardSidebar to mimic the appearance of a flexdashboard. However, the menu by default is aligned to the right (*Edit:* now aligned to the left via `htmltools::tagQuery`):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmltools)
library(shinydashboard)

modifiedDashboardHeader <- tagQuery(dashboardHeader(
  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
          tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionLink(inputId = "tab1dropdown", label = "Tab 1")),
          tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionLink(inputId = "tab2dropdown", label = "Tab 2")),
          tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionLink(inputId = "tab3dropdown", label = "Tab 3"))
  )
))$find(".navbar-custom-menu")$removeAttrs("style")$addAttrs("style" = "float: left; margin-left: 0px;")$allTags()

ui <- dashboardPage(
  modifiedDashboardHeader,
  dashboardSidebar(
    textInput("test", "test"),
    actionButton("test_2", "test 2"),
    hidden(sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarID",
      menuItem("tab1", tabName = "tab1"),
      menuItem("tab2", tabName = "tab2"),
      menuItem("tab3", tabName = "tab3")
    ))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem("tab1", "Tab 1 content"),
      tabItem("tab2", "Tab 2 content"),
      tabItem("tab3", "Tab 3 content")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tab1dropdown, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = "tab1")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab2dropdown, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = "tab2")
  })
  observeEvent(input$tab3dropdown, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebarID", selected = "tab3")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

PS: also please check [shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(leftUi = tagList(...))](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/enhanced-header.html#improved-dropdownmenu) as an alternative.

Comment: Indeed the placement of the tabs is not ideal, I would prefer it to the left. But I am surprised by the complexity of using navbar tabs in `shinydashboard`, when it is possible with just a few lines using `flexdashboard`

Comment: shinydashboard or rather AdminLTE simply uses another navigation approach. In my eyes it wasn't intended to navigate via tabs in the header.

Comment: Needed some manual adjustment, but now the tabs are aligned to the left. Please see my edit.

Comment: The alignment is not perfect again, there is some overlap between tabs when I hover them. Maybe this is due to screensize.

Comment: @bretauv I just came across this question again. We can properly align the tabs to the left via `htmltools::tagQuery`. Please see my edit.