# Hide the main header of the shinydashboard without hiding the title section

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to know how could I reduce the height of the header section on the main header of the shiny dashboard to `0` by leaving the height of the tilte section untouchable in order to make the `tabsetPanel()` of the main body to be in the same level with the title.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "saddasda",
                  # Set height of dashboardHeader
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                          tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 0px}"),
                  )
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id="inTabset",
      tabPanel("show",
  ),
  tabPanel("Hide")
))
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you trying to realize something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918445/reproduce-a-flexdashboard-layout-with-shinydashboard/62929783#62929783)? Furthermore, are you aware of `shinydashboardPlus::dropdownBlock`? Please see a demo [here](https://dgranjon.shinyapps.io/shinydashboardPlusDemo/).

Comment: yes this seems good